# PHP / SQL and modularity

Tags: php, sql, module, procedure

I'm currently working on a small home-made PHP framework.

I would like it to automatically manage things like user connections, user groups, and access rights for both users and groups.

However some websites may not need some of these things. For example, blog and showcase sites might not need groups or page access management.

In order to avoid having unused stuff included in the framework, I would like to divide this into 3 separate modules (and maybe more by the next). Each of these modules would have its own SQL installation script that would create the module's own tables, and alter the other tables they have dependencies with (adding columns, foreign keys, etc).

Let's imagine we have the 3 modules : "User", "Group", "Access".

Now let's imagine that all of the 3 modules are included, the database would look like :

```
user :
- id
- login
- password

group :
- id
- label

right :
- id
- label

user_group :
- userId
- groupId

user_right :
- userId
- rightId

group_right :
- groupId
- rightId
```

The user module SQL script would create the user table.

The group module SQL script would create the group and user_group tables.

The access module SQL script would create the right table and... this is where my problem is : will it also create the user_right and group_right tables ? To determine that I need to check inside of the access module installation SQL script if the other two modules are included (or at least the group module since there can't be rights without users).

Is there any way to do something like :

```
if table exists 'group' create table 'group_right' ...
```

I would also like this to be cross database, if possible.

I could also have PHP scripts instead of SQL scripts that would test if, say, the module folder exists, and perform the right queries using PDO, but that looks a bit dirty.

Any suggestion about how I could do that is welcome :) Thanks for reading.

Comment: The only way I know to do this with mysql is to query the `information_schema` database, which makes me think that a cross-db solution would just require writing each migration more than once. In order to reduce repetition, PHP migration scripts (at least to test what needs to be done) might be the best way.

Comment: Your question made me curious enough to go dig through the rails source a bit. You can see that they use separate adapter code to translate their migrations into commands accepted by the specific DB backend: [sqlite adapter](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb) vs [mysql adapter](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb) (I know you're working in PHP, but I think rails can teach us something about framework design.)

Comment: Thanks. I don't know this language though, what am I supposed to look at in these files ?

Comment: For example, the function `table_exists?` is defined in both files, and in both cases it calls `tables`, which uses some sql code crafted for that specific db engine. It just strengthens my hunch that creating a multi-db solution probably requires handling each db separately. BTW, the language is [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/).